# Inconsistent date time format for German locale

Tags: java, android, datetime

The following code produces different output in Android and standard jdk

```
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
    Locale.GERMAN);
    final String today = df.format(new Date());
```

Output:

Android: `Mi., 24 Jul 2013 12:33:12 +0200`

Standard jdk: `Mi, 24 Jul 2013 12:33:12 +0200`

In the server side, It is throwing parse exception, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use standard UTC date time format. Not all locales are supported by JDK. So it is safe to use Locale.US specially useful when exchanging data over platform.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest a workaround:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
            Locale.GERMAN);
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = df.getDateFormatSymbols();
    String[] swd = {"", "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"};
    dfs.setShortWeekdays(swd);
    df.setDateFormatSymbols(dfs);
```

now it will format dates into

```
Mi, 24 Jul 2013 12:33:12 +0200
```

in both standard Java and Android

Comment: This could be a solutions when I'm developing client side (Android). Imagine other people are also using the server side API. FYI, iOS  also produces same output as Android.