# Unable to parse date String to Date

Tags: java, date, time

im want to parse a date String to a Date. I was looking in some other questions, but I didn't find an answer.

```
String mail_delivered = "31.10.2013 17:57:58 CET";

try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.GERMAN);
    Date result =  df.parse(mail_delivered);  
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error message is java.text.ParseException: `Unparseable date: "[31.10.2013 17:57:58 CET]"` and I don't know what's wrong.

Can you help me please.
Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: ok. i canged it to english, but i'have still the same problem. I wouldn't like to change the input, because it comes from a mail database. Any other ideas?

```
String mail_delivered = "31.10.2013 17:57:58 CET";

try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result =  df.parse(mail_delivered);  
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

I found the problem. I was blind. The Sting from the Database was `[31.10.2013 17:57:58 CET]`, not `31.10.2013 17:57:58 CET`

Thank you.

Comment: use - instead of . in dd.MM.yyyy

Comment: Problem seems to be with the last part... when that's removed, it works. Maybe "CET" is different in german?

Comment: Works fine for me..gives this o/p for me.. Thu Oct 31 22:27:58 IST 2013

Comment: p0ssible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831696/inconsistent-date-time-format-for-german-locale

Comment: Those three-letter codes for time zones are neither standardized nor unique. And now I learn from the answers below that they can be localized. Using this string format is asking for trouble. If you can get your data delivered in the unambiguous [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `2014-01-11T12:21:05+08:00`, you'll be better off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In German, "Central European Time" is "Mitteleuropäische Zeit", so if you want to use `Locale.GERMAN`, change `CET` to `MEZ` and it works.

```
String mail_delivered = "31.10.2013 17:57:58 MEZ";
```

For a list of all the legal time zone strings for a given locale, use this:

```
DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).getZoneStrings()
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I didn't think of that because in the german wikipedia you sign your input also  with CET.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       //Middle European Time (MET or MEZ-German)
        String mail_delivered = "31.10.2013 17:57:58 MET";
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z",Locale.GERMAN);
            Date result =  df.parse(mail_delivered);  
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output :- Thu Oct 31 22:27:58 IST 2013

Comment: You are right.H specify (0-23) format where h specify (1-12).I was running both format program and pasted the small one.I have changed the posted answer.Thanks.